# Mac + RStudio: Upgrade hardware or keep downgraded software?

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

Other R-users may well agree that the [`RStudio` IDE](http://www.rstudio.org/) has been an extremely effective way to increase productivity.  But, with the release of `RStudio 0.96.122`, neither 32-bit Macs nor OSX < 10.6 (Snow Leopard) are supported.  I run OSX 10.6, but on a 32-bit Intel Mac; hence, my choices are

1. Accept that this will be the last functional release for my system and deal with its limitations.
2. Complain to the developers - I'd rather not.
3. Buy expensive new hardware, i.e. a new Mac.
4. Stop using `R` and/or `RStudio` - no way!

So my question is:  At what point is it wise to upgrade hardware rather than keep a previous release of software such as `RStudio`?  Is 64-bit that important for "normal" users?

Clearly `RStudio` is actively developed by some really clever programmers but, damn, Macs are expensive.

Comment: You could Parallels+Windows+RStudio latest?

Comment: You could wipe out OSX and install linux (facing the same issue, I am tempted to do just that)

Comment: RStudio is very pretty but ... does it do anything that e.g. Emacs+ESS doesn't/can't?

Comment: Having a direct interface with git repositories is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing the same issue. My guess is that you could [install R on Amazon EC2](http://travisnelson.net/2011/05/05/ec2-micro-instance-of-rstudio/). I'm going to try that myself in the coming days. I'll come back here to ask how to use a proxy to secure the result.